# Managing content for multiple users within ArcGIS Collector App?

Tags: arcgis-online, security, feature-service, arcgis-collector

I have a hundreds of people collecting data.  Each user has an ArcGIS Online login. I want to be able to filter content visible in the ArcGIS Collector App based on the logged in user, but don't want the maintenance burden of having a different web map for each user.  I have a field in my feature service which indicates which the user should see the data.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit editing by user so that users only edit their features:https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-layers.htm

For user specific data access controls I have seen a demo where the server dynamically filters the response data based on authenticated user. This was done with custom ArcGIS Server SOE developed by Esri Professional Services. I don't know if it works with Portal / hosted services. Ask your rep.

Obviously this would not available in ArcGIS Online.

There is an automated map publishing solution that could be used to generate the maps with individual query filters for specific users. http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/automated-setup/

Comment: yeah, this generally what I found.  I'm surprised AGOL doesn't have more fine-grained access controls being that it already has a user/groups model.

Comment: Working on it...

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by revoking the select privilege for the objects you don't want visible by X user. If you want the user to "see" or have access to the object, the select privilege needs to be granted.

Comment: Are you saying its possible to revoke the select privilege for  a subset of records within a hosted-feature service layer?  If so, do you have a link to where this is documented?

Comment: Not for a subset of records. Your question makes it sound like it was at the object level.

Answer (score -1):

For some projects, we have been using geoodk and its possible in a project. We are using this for [EMAIV](http://uizentrum.de/en/environmental-monitoring-analysis-and-interactive-visualization-emaiv/).